# Detect if iframe inside a div is loaded by only changing the code of an external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="mydiv"> 
<iframe>
</iframe>
</div>
```

I would like to fire an alert message when the contents of mydiv are fully loaded.
This should be executed from an external JS file: javascript.js and without making any changes to the html page itself. (so onload() cant be used).

Thanks.

Comment: Is `javascript.js` file already linked via `<script>` tag in the HTML page? If not, you're hosed.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the `div` element by `id`
2. Get the `iframe` in the `div` by using `getElementsByTagName("iframe")`
3. Use `addEventListener` to listen to the `load` event of the `iframe`. In the below example, I show how you can use a reusable function for the `load` event handler, and note that the `e` parameter can be used to give you access to the event details, including `e.target`

```js
function doLoad(e) {
  alert("iframe is loaded.");
}
var the_div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var the_iframe = the_div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
the_iframe.addEventListener("load", doLoad);
the_iframe.src = "/"; // replace '/' with page you want to load
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <iframe>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, Thanks